# cloth modifier for not conected mesh

Tags: cloth-simulation

I have this dress

[image]

As you cans see the white part is not direcly connected to the mesh of the skirt.

[image]

If I add a cloth modifier then the white part just falls down.

[image]

How can I connect the white part to the skirt such that it followes the movement of the skirt. I have tried to make it part of the pin group of the cloth modifier but then it has a constant diameter.

Comment: Hello, is there a reason why it is not part of the blue dress object?

Comment: The white stuff is part of the blue dress object. It is all one object, the mesh is just not connected. I don't make this model. I imported it in to blender.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could bridge between the 2 meshes and delete the faces only:

[image]

Don't forget to enable the *Self Collisions* option. Result once animated:

[image]

Another trick would be to give the cloth simulation to a cage object that has roughly the shape of your dress, give your dress object a *Mesh Deform* modifier with the cage as target, parent the dess to the cage:

[image]

When you animate the cage, the dress follows:

[image]